# jpql query with date literal causes IllegalArgumentException

Tags: jpql

I am trying to write query with date literal:

```
SELECT r 
FROM Restaurant r 
LEFT JOIN r.dishes dh ON dh.date = {d '2019-12-31'} 
GROUP BY r
```

But when running I get an error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '{'

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try use only date in ISO format

```
SELECT r 
FROM Restaurant r 
LEFT JOIN r.dishes dh ON dh.date = '2019-12-31'
GROUP BY r
```